# PowerShell $xml.NameTable is null

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file that contains elements with namespaces that I am wishing to read using PowerShell.

Example XML:

```
    <ns0:Members xmlns:ns0="http://my.domain.com/subsite">
        <Member>
            <MemberDetails>
                <Name>Blah de Blah Blah</Name>
                <Email>blah@lost.com</Email>
            </MemberDetails>
        </Member>
    </Members>
```

From some examples I found online, I wrote the following PowerShell to read the XML:

```
   function Get-ScriptDirectory
    {
        return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    }

    $xmlFile = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) "MyXmlFile.xml"
    [xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFile         
    $ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
    $ns.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://my.domain.com/subsite")
    $node = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ns0:Members")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Xml.XmlNamespaceManager.
```

I searched online for the error but the only post I found suggested double-checking that the version of PowerShell was version 2.

I ran `$Host.Version`, which gave me:

```
    Major  Minor  Build  Revision
    -----  -----  -----  --------
    2      0      -1     -1
```

When I stepped through the script using PowerGui Editor, I discovered that `$xml.NameTable` is null.

Can anyone explain why and what I can do to fix it?

On another note, none of the methods I've tried to select the `Members` element has worked including `Select-Xml` and `$xmlDoc.SelectNodes`. The only way I could get it was using:

```
    $xmlDoc.Members
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here. In `$ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable` you use the `$xml` variable, while your xmldoc is actually `$xmlDoc`

Comment: @Graimer That's what the example I found used - I wasn't sure if it should be $xmlDoc or whether $xml was something inbuilt

Comment: @Graimer I tried changing it to $xmlDoc and that resolved the issue. Can you please provide your above response as an answer so I can mark it as the answer? Moral of the story - just because someone else says the code works doesn't mean they've actually provided you with working code ;)

Comment: nothing built in, just normal to call the xml content for $xml :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
    {
        return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    }

    $xmlFile = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) "MyXmlFile.xml"
    [xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFile         
    $ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xmlDoc.NameTable
    $ns.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://my.domain.com/subsite")
    $node = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ns0:Members")
```

Fixed typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Select-Xml` like so:

```
$ns = @{ns0='http://my.domain.com/subsite'}
$xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//ns0:Members' -Namespace $ns
```

Comment: Thanks :) Your answer also worked for me once I changed $xml to $xmlDoc.