# Powershell XML content manipulation

Tags: regex, xml, powershell

I have an XML file with several entries using same keys and values handling credentials with PowerShell, constructed by `Explort-Clixml`. An example:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Collections.Hashtable</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <DCT>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">fabrikam</S>
        <Obj N="Value" RefId="1">
          <TN RefId="1">
            <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
            <T>System.Object</T>
          </TN>
          <Props>
            <S N="UserName">admin@fabrikam.com</S>
            <SS N="Password">01000000...</SS>
          </Props>
        </Obj>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">contoso</S>
        <Obj N="Value" RefId="2">
          <TNRef RefId="1" />
          <Props>
            <S N="UserName">admin@contoso.com</S>
            <SS N="Password">01000000...</SS>
          </Props>
        </Obj>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">adatum</S>
        <Obj N="Value" RefId="3">
          <TNRef RefId="1" />
          <Props>
            <S N="UserName">admin@adatum.com</S>
            <SS N="Password">01000000...</SS>
          </Props>
        </Obj>
      </En>
    </DCT>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

The same `Export-Clixml` handles adding new entries to the list (as hashtables), but I'm struggling when I'd have to modify entries I already have.

1) If I specify to delete an item named `contoso`, what is the best way to seek, select and remove everything from that `<En>` entirely?

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content file.xml)
$xml.SelectNodes("//Objs/Obj/DCT/En")
```

... yields nothing at all, whereas

```
$xml.Objs.Obj.DCT.En.s
```

works perfect and returns the list of entries by their name. I would need to remove an entire `<En>` element per given value for `<S N="Key">...</S>`. Trying to catch the correct entry with

```
$xml.Objs.Obj.DCT.En.ChildNodes | ? { '#text' -contains 'contoso' }
```

returns nothing.

2) `RefId` value in `Obj` is an auto incremented number. If I remove `contoso` between the other two entries, what would be the best way to seek and replace the value of `RefId` in `fabrikam` and `adatum` so they're in order (1,2) again? A noteworthy point here is that *only* the first `<En>` in the list has sub-elements for `<TN RefId>` element, the others do not.

Comment: "Best way" is usually subjective.

Comment: "Most reliable considering the scenario" then, perhaps.

Comment: Don't use regex to manipulate xml files. It's the wrong tool and that's exactly why you are struggling with these problems. You need a tool which understands the structure of xml files. PowerShell is an option - convert the file to an xml object, manipulate that, write the manipulated object back to a file.

Comment: load your xml like that: $xml = [XML]get-content -path "pathtoxml"  after that you can use $xml.selectnode("//here xpath") and xpath to finde your node. As en example you can remove a node with $YourXMLObject.removechildenode

Comment: I changed the example a bit so you can see the problem is that if I lookup the item "workstations", I can't delete its child items but I would need to remove the <entry> around it (as in its parent container).

Comment: Where is the code you've tried so far? your comment here suggests different to the OP requirements and I'm finding it confusing. I 'think' you want to look for a node called Workstations, if it's found and has child elements populated then you want to omit the parent <entry></entry> nodes and leave just the workstations node and it's children??

Comment: Side Note: you have many unclosed tags in your xml, please close them ;).

Comment: Clarified the original post yet again. @shA.t yes, I do, Export-Clixml does that.

Comment: So, what about `<data key="3">`? - use `<data key="3" />` instead ;).

Comment: The original XML is constructed with Export-Clixml which doesn't close the tags like that and it's not something I want to interfere with.

Comment: Your $xml = [xml](Get-Content file.xml)
$xml.SelectNodes("//entries/entry") isn't working because your XML file is not valid XML data, please close the data tags as shA.t has suggested. You will find that your $xml.SelectNodes will actually yield results then.

Comment: Try this XPath instead: [`//entry[item="workstations"]`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/V29UviM8r) -HTH ;).

Comment: please remember xpaths are strings, so //entry[item='workstations'] - but this is not going to work if he has invalid XML

Comment: $xml.entries.entry works instead but I'm yet to figure out how to use that further. As I said I cannot alter the XML format, as it is constructed by Powershell's builtin Export-Clixml cmdlet. If XPaths cannot be used with it then I'll have to find another way to work with.

Comment: How are you loading invalid XML with $xml = [xml](get-content file.xml) - It should be stating: ```Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The 'data' start tag on line 12 position 6 does not match the end tag of 'entry'. Line 17, position 5."
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml = [xml](Get-Content file.xml)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument```

Comment: I don't know what to answer that. Try with Powershell; `Get-Credential | Export-Clixml output.xml` (enter anything when prompted) and you'll see what I'm actually working with. To me it's XML, if it's interpreted as something else then I'm even more lost than I thought. I used a more simple example not to paste hundreds of lines of code here as I thought it'd behave the same way.

Comment: ok, good. so your actual xml output IS in a correct format, you've just given a remedied example data that is infact invald, i'll edit your post to make it valid XML.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean and where the error lies within the example. I'll edit the actual case to the example so it can be dealt with proper attributes.

Comment: you might find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259590/access-text-property-of-xmlattribute-in-powershell

Comment: I found that post earlier and tried it with my scenario, but `$attr = $xml.SelectNodes("//Obj/DCT/En/S[@N='Key']/@value")` returns nothing - yet again.

Comment: I think I'm on a right track now after finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085544/2511543, I needed to add a namespace definition for the schema used when using XPaths.